# Flutter Theme not working properly. Refreshes only on Hot-Reload

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, themes

i have created two Themes for my Flutter App with a seed color for light and dark theme.

```
ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
        seedColor: Colors.green,
        brightness: Brightness.light,)

....more settings);
```

```
ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
        seedColor: Colors.blue,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,)

....more settings);
```

this is my ThemeManager class:

```
class ThemeManager with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode _themeMode = StoragePreferences.getThemeMode() == true
      ? ThemeMode.dark
      : ThemeMode.light;
  get themeMode => _themeMode;

  toggleTheme(bool isDark) {
    _themeMode = isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Calling and checking.

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    _themeManager.removeListener(themeListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _themeManager.addListener(themeListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  themeListener() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

Themes are applied correctly for whole App if switching theme. Except when i´m trying to set the color for ListTile depending on theme.

I tried this code to set color for ListTile:

```
ExpansionTile(
backgroundColor: Theme.of(context)
                 .colorScheme
                 .primary

expandedAlignment: Alignment.topLeft,
...
...
...
```

When starting app it shows the correct color. if theme is switched by user to dark theme, ListTile color stays same as before (in this case green of light theme) rest of Theme changes correct.

Color of ListTile changes only, if I´m hot Reloading app (in this case blue of dark theme) same procedure if switching back to light theme from now.

Can you please help me finding my mistake?

EDIT:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('de', 'DE'),
      ],
      title: 'TestApp',
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
      themeMode: _themeManager.themeMode,
      home: TestPageView(),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Where do you inject ThemeManager into your context above MaterialApp?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz edited my post above

Comment: What class is listening to the change notifier in order to rebuild, `TestPageView`? If so, please show the code of the widget that is listening and building.